# Probability of exactly $2$ sixes in $3$ dice rolls where $2$ dice have $6$ on $2$ faces?

Tags: probability, dice

Three dice are rolled. One is fair and the other two have 6 on two faces.

Find the probability of rolling exactly 2 sixes.

My textbook gives an answer of $\frac{20}{147}$ but I get an answer of: $$\frac{1}{6}\frac{2}{6}\frac{4}{6}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{4}{6}\frac{2}{6}+\frac{5}{6}\frac{2}{6}\frac{2}{6}=\frac{8}{216}+\frac{8}{216}+\frac{20}{216}=\frac{36}{216}=\frac{1}{6}$$

I just want to know where I am going wrong or could the textbook be mistaken ?

Comment: I get the same result you get, via the same argument.

Comment: $147=3\times 7^2$ is a strange denominator.  As your calculation shows, you get a sum of terms each with denominator a power of $6$...hard to imagine where the factor of $7$ comes in.  Of course, I am assuming that these are otherwise ordinary six sided dice.

Comment: @lulu Thanks , I also experimented with 147 and find it strange. It must be an error in the textbook.

Comment: Ha!  I get the official answer if I assume that the two unusual dice have seven sides instead of six.  That is they have two $6's$ and five others.  To be sure, I'd never have thought of this reading were it not for the $7^2$ in the denominator.

Comment: @lulu How can a seven sides dice stands up? :)

Comment: @lulu Haha , great. So they must of meant a six sided dice where the six side was twice as probable as the other sides. Thanks. Write an brief answer and it's yours.

Comment: @user: You make a 'cylindrical' dice with $5$ faces forming a pentagonal cylinder. By using uniform material and choosing the appropriate height, you can ensure that each face has equal likelihood of being at the bottom.

Comment: @user you could also take regular heptahedrons and consider the numbers that end up facing down, I guess

Comment: @PauloMourão: There is no regular heptahedron.

Comment: @user21820 ah true, I forgot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that the official answer is correct if you make the (unnatural) assumption that the two non-standard dice have seven sides (two of which show $6$).

In that case the answer is $$\frac 27\times \frac 27\times \frac 56+2\times \frac 27\times \frac 57\times \frac 16=\frac {20}{147}$$

To be sure, this was arrived at by reverse engineering, not by any sensible reading of the problem.

Comment: Great detective work, sussing out a harebrained problem.  (Apologies to any hares out there.)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution seems correct, indeed also by the naif definition of probability we obtain

$$p=\frac{\text{#favorauble cases}}{\text{#total cases}}=\frac{8+8+20}{6^3}=\frac16$$